# How can I switch between detail views?

Tags: need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

In NFS SHIFT 2 I cannot switch between these mods in PC:
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Can anyone please help me?
Where do I need to set the key for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you play with the keyboard, you must select telemetry view, and switch between mods with the 'X' key, which is set as the default. I don't think you can set a custom key for it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a button that will cycle through HUD options. Go to your controls and look for the key bound to "Cycle HUD" or a similar option, and press that. itll cycle between full hud, hud without mirror, lite hud, no hud and telemetry. what you have up is telemetry.